# Java DbUtils MySQL How set param when call a stored procedures

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons-dbutils

I have a probleme with call a procedure, I want to set two paramams. In procedure first param have to be a int and secod time. I did this :

```
beans = (List) qRunner.query(conn, "call mpklocal.LCD_GetDispInfoChange_TEST(?, CURTIME()  )", timtableId ,
                      new BeanListHandler(AnotherBusInBusStop.class));
```

when I close a program I see this :

```
Java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CURTIME())' at line 1 Query: call mpklocal.LCD_GetDispInfoChange_TEST(?,SELECT CURTIME()) Parameters: [657983]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:351)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:180)
```

Comment: Do you ever bind that `?` parameter to something?  Does the raw query execute on MariaDB with no problems?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when I do it on MariaDB on workbench all works correct